# What's wrong with the obvious argument that the unstable motivic category is an $\infty$-topos?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, motivic-homotopy, infinity-topos-theory

Fix a base scheme $S$, and let $Sm_S$ be the (ordinary) category of smooth schemes over $S$.

- Denote by $Psh(Sm_S)$ the $\infty$-category of $\infty$-presheaves on $Sm_S$.
- Let $Sh_{Nis}(Sm_S)\subseteq Psh(Sm_S)$ be the full subcategory of presheaves which are sheaves for the Nisnevich topology. Denote $a_{Nis}: Psh(Sm_S)^\to_\leftarrow Sh_{Nis}(Sm_S): i_{Nis}$ the inclusion / sheafification adjunction. Note that $a_{Nis}$ and $i_{Nis}$ are left exact and accessible.
- Let $Sh_{\mathbb A^1}(Sm_S) \subseteq Psh(Sm_S)$ be the full subcategory of presheaves which are $\mathbb A^1$-local. Denote by $a_{\mathbb A^1}: Psh(Sm_S)^\to_\leftarrow Sh_{\mathbb A^1}(Sm_S): i_{\mathbb A^1}$ the inclusion / localization adjunction. Again, $a_{\mathbb A^1}$ and $i_{\mathbb A^1}a_{\mathbb A^1}$, are left exact (**EDIT**: This is the problem -- $a_{\mathbb A^!}$ is not left exact!) and accessible.
- Let $Spaces_S \subseteq Psh(Sm_S)$ be the intersection $Sh_{Nis}(Sm_S) \cap Sh_{\mathbb A^1}(Sm_S)$. I'll call this *the unstable motivic category*.

It's a fact that $Spaces_S$ is not an $\infty$-topos (cf. section 4.3 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.08467)). Nevertheless, here is a proof that it is an $\infty$-topos:

We exhibit $Spaces_S$ as a left exact localization of $Psh(Sm_S)$. Let $F: Psh(Sm_S) \to Psh(Sm_S)$ be the composite $i_{\mathbb A^1}a_{\mathbb A^1}i_{Nis} a_{Nis}$. Then $F$ is left exact and accessible. Then for any $Y \in Spaces_S$, we have that $Y$ is local with respect to the map $X \to F(X)$ for any $X \in Psh(Sm_S)$. By induction, $Y$ is also local with respect to $X \to F^\kappa(X)$ for any ordinal $\kappa$. Since $F$ is accessible, the chain $F^\bullet(X)$ eventually stabilizes at some $\kappa$; at this point we have an object of $Spaces_S$, so that the localization functor $L_{Mot}: Psh(Sm_S) \to Spaces_S$ is given by $X \mapsto F^{\infty}(X)$, where $\infty$ is the size of the universe.

Now, $L_{Mot} = F^\infty$ is a filtered colimit of left exact functors on a presheaf category, and therefore left exact. So $Spaces_S$ is an $\infty$-topos.

**Question:**
What went wrong? Is the argument flawed, or one of the premises? I've cut a few corners, but not in ways that I *think* are inherently dodgy. I'd be happy to expand on such points.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that the construction of $L_{Mot}$ is correct  -- at least that's what it sounds like when motivic people describe it. Formally, I think the argument shows that for sufficiently large $\kappa$, (1) $X \to F^\kappa(X)$ is a map with respect to which motivic spaces are local and (2) $F^\kappa(X)$ is a motivic space. This just means that $F^\kappa(X)$ is a reflection of $X$ in $Spaces_S$.

Comment: Why does $F$ so-defined preserve colimits? PS I deleted my last comment since I realized that L should be a left rather than right adjoint.

Comment: $F$ doesn't preserve colimits. $F^\infty$ does (after restricting its codomain to $Spaces_S$), but that's only established indirectly. This is analogous tot he Grothendieck plus construction in ordinary topos theory or the $T_n$ functor in Goodwillie calculus -- although the iterates of the functor converge to something that preserves colimits (after restricting the codomain), the functor itself does not.

Comment: I think I see the problem, but I'm not sure I am correct. I don't think $a_{\mathbb{A}^1}$ is actually left-exact or that $Psh_{\mathbb{A}^1}(Sm_S)$ is in fact a topos at all. My intuition is that if it were, it should be definable by a Grothendieck topology, but I could be wrong!

Comment: That's the one thing I don't know how to prove, although I believe I've been told before that it's true. Perhaps I'm misremembering. And perhaps the subtlety is this: from one localization you can always universally generate a stronger localization which is left exact, so there is "a" topos that one might call $Sh_{\mathbb A^1}(Sm_S)$ which does have a left exact localization functor. But perhaps it's just not the same as $\mathbb A^1$ localization. If this is the case, then the reason for the failure to be a topos is in some sense much less subtle than I'd been led to believe.

Comment: It seems like it must be false, since the rest of the proof looks solid. The only other question I had involved those unit maps for F, since F is not a left-adjoint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80643/discussion-between-harry-gindi-and-tim-campion).

Comment: The homotopy localization functor preserves finite products but not all finite limits.

Comment: I see -- the Grothendieck topology generated by $\mathbb A^1$ localization includes as a singleton cover the graph $X \to X\times \mathbb A^1$ of any function on $X$. By pullback, the inclusion of any hypersurface into $X$ is also a singleton cover, for $X$ affine. By composition, the map $\emptyset \to X$ is a singleton cover for every affine $X$. But for example, $\mathbb G_m$ is $\mathbb A^1$-invariant but not local with respect to $\emptyset \to \mathbb G_m$ (and $\mathbb G_m$ is affine). So $\mathbb A^1$-localization is indeed not left exact.